# How to get count of Number of rows by month using date in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which looks like

Table1

```
ID      Date
1       2018-01-01 15:04:03
2       2018-01-02 18:06:05
3       2018-01-03 23:21:12
4       2018-02-01 15:04:03
5       2018-02-02 18:06:05
6       2018-02-03 23:21:12
```

I want the count based on Month either in `JAN-18` format or in `2018-01` format.

Required output:

```
Month   Count
JAN-18  3
FEB-18  3
```

Comment: Convert the MySQL Date formatInclude `GROUP BY month(Date)` at the end of your select query.

Comment: Use `DATE_FORMAT(`Date`, "%b-%I")` to convert date

Comment: @EazySam, I think you mean `%y` or `%Y` instead of `%I`

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` the year and the month:

```
select year(Date), month(Date), count(*)
from table1
group by year(Date), month(Date)
```

Formatting the output shouldn't be that tricky, but I don't know MySQL...

Try `concat(cast(year(Date) as char(4)),'-',cast(month(Date) as char(2)))`.

Comment: I can concatenate the Month and Year to get `JAN-18` format...right??

Comment: you can use MONTH() OR MONTHNAME(), see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname

Comment: and you can use CONCAT() to concat Strings: see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: you can use DATE_FORMAT(), see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 1):

```
select DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%b-%y'), count(*) from table1 group by YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
```

- %b:  Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec)
- %y:  Year, numeric (two digits)

see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%b')),'-',year(Date)), count(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY CONCAT(UPPER(DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%b')),'-',year(Date))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use the `DATE_FORMAT()` function:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m'), COUNT(*)
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m')
```

`%m` in the mask will give the month's number (01-12) and `%Y` is the 4-digit year; use the following to get the other format you mentioned:

```
SELECT UPPER(DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%b-%y')), COUNT(*)
  FROM Table1
 GROUP BY UPPER(DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%b-%y'))
```

`%b` is the month's name abbreviated, but capitalized rather than all-uppercase; `%y` is the 2-digit year.

Answer (score 0):

The format yyyy-mm is sortable, so use this to group by:

```
select date_format(date, 'Y-m') as month, count(*)
from table1
group by month
order by month;
```

(Grouping by the alias name is not valid in standard SQL, but in MySQL it is and it gets the query very readable.)